# Change already saved information in database to be updated with another php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I really didn't want to bring this into here as I was sure it should work and it must be a silly error. However I'm trying to change the value of a column in my database after a button is pressed. Now I have echoed random things out to make sure that the button pressed is posting correct to the PHP file. But the code posting the change to the database doesn't seam to be working and I really can't understand why so before I go on talking to much here is the code ...

```
      function sound2($user_name){
  $usrpref2 = "2";
    $sql=("UPDATE members SET usrpref = '$usrpref2' WHERE user_name = '$user_name'");
    $sdone2 = mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

I have also tried it like this where my or die message would appear to show that it wasn't working ...

```
 function sound2($user_name){
    $usrpref3 = "2";
    $sdone3 = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET usrpref = '$usrpref2' WHERE user_name = '$user_name'") or die ("Failed to save preference");


  }
```

If anyone can see what is going wrong with this that would be great, I have echoed out both values used the $user_name and the $usrpref values. At the top of the page it also connects to my database through ...

```
    include_once("scripts/connect.php");
```

Many thanks to anyone with an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

extra code ...

my index has the following code which posts to the php ...

```
        $("#save2").click(function() {
        $.post('userpreference.php', { name: user_name, save:"sound2"}, function(data){
          $('#errorrreport3').html(data);
           });   
       });
```

#### And then my php does the following ...

```
  if( $_REQUEST["name"])
 {
  $user_name = $_REQUEST['name'];
 };  

  //------------------------------------------------

   if( $_REQUEST["save"])
 {
  $save = $_REQUEST['save'];

};
if($save == 'sound2') {
 sound2($user_name);

};
```

If the above helps :) then there you go thanks :)

Lastly I will just add I have tried both Integer and Varchar in my database for saving the number into all I need to do is save / change the number of a column, annoyingly I have done this before with time. However the code is almost the same apart from the variables used.

Comment: This is defintely too few code for analysing anything. Besides that, you really shouldn't use the MySQL extension anymore!

Comment: In your function `sound2` can you echo the `$user_name` value?  Unless you already did...  I see that you echoed them, but I wanted to make sure it's passing it correctly to your function.

Comment: Have you tried to output `mysql_error()` to see what is happening?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sound2($user_name){
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET usrpref = 2 WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "'";
    var_dump($sql);
    $sdone2 = mysql_query($sql); 
}
```

Try dumping out your SQL and running it manually in your DB query utility.

Comment: They weren't necessary, but this does not solve the problem at all. It results in 100% equal code.

Comment: no luck with that one either :/ I'll have a little play around with that see if I can get it working

Comment: Being new (<50rep) I could not post a comment. Was just pointing that out.

Comment: yes it is echoing out fine up to the point where as in the past with the following code .. 
    $sdone3 = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET usrpref = '$usrpref2' WHERE user_name = '$user_name'") or die ("Failed to save preference");

It also came back with 'Failed to save preference', if it had failed to reach my database it would have echoed that out so I am sure it got to my database.

Comment: Is the usrpref column an INT? If so, remove the single quotes around $usrpref2. Do you have access to your mysql error logs?

Comment: can we chat somewhere out of here jas it might be easier

Comment: Don't think I can send a PM in SO. Not enough rep to use SO chat. You?

Comment: I can't chat as you haven't enough points :( saddly anyway I have taken it out of the marks and nothing has happened. now in mine I am putting the number I need into a variable before trying to save it into the database can I just go direct and save the number?

Comment: If that variable is always 2, yes you can.

Comment: ye it is always 2 edit your post above if you need more space to type than this comment thing

Comment: saddly no luck there either  :/

Comment: And a refresh of the row in the table shows it is not updating the usrpref column to 2?

Comment: string(60) "UPDATE members SET usrpref = 2 WHERE user_name = 'I am gnat'"